# subtraction give strange result [Java]

Tags: java

I'm trying to calculate the difference of x and y of two points, but the result of the substraction don't match with the value that i'm printing.

here's some of my code:

this is the subtraction operation. all the value are int.

```
differenceX = positionX - point[i].X;
differenceY = positionY - point[i].Y;
```

with this line i check all the value

```
System.out.println(i + "\t" + point[i].X + "\t" + point[i].Y + "\t" + positionX + "\t" + positionY + "\t" + differenceX + "\t" + differenceY);
```

and there are some of the result

```
index   P1X     P1Y     P2X     P2Y      DX    DY
0       53      49      50      50       2     -4
1       52      47      50      50       3     -2
2       50      49      50      50       0     -4
3       49      46      50      50      -4     -1
4       52      50      50      50       3      0

0       48      54      50      50      -3      1
1       47      52      50      50      -2      3
2       50      54      50      50       0      1
3       54      51      50      50       1      4
4       47      50      50      50      -2      0
```

the two value Point[i].X and Point[i].Y are randomly initialized with random.nextInt.
UNIT_SIZe is the size of the point that will be displayed.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        point[i] = new Point(UNIT_SIZE, random.nextInt(SCREEN_WIDTH), random.nextInt(SCREEN_HEIGHT));
    }
```

this is the function where i have the problem

```
    int differenceX;
    int differenceY;
    int positionY = 50;
    int positionX = 50;
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        differenceX = positionX - point[i].X;
        differenceY = positionY - point[i].Y;


        if(differenceX > 0) {
            direction = 'R';
        } else if(differenceX < 0) {
            direction = 'L';
        } else if(differenceX == 0) {
            direction = '\0';
        }

        if(differenceY > 0) {
            direction2 = 'B';
        } else if(differenceY < 0) {
            direction2 = 'U';
        } else if(differenceY == 0) {
            direction2 = '\0';
        }

        
        if(differenceY > positionY && differenceY < UNIT_SIZE || differenceY < positionY && differenceY > positionY-UNIT_SIZE) {
            point[i].move(differenceY, '\0', direction2);
        }
        if(differenceX > positionX && differenceX < UNIT_SIZE || differenceX < positionX && differenceX > positionX-UNIT_SIZE) {
            point[i].move(differenceX, direction, '\0');
        }
        

        point[i].move(UNIT_SIZE, direction, direction2);
        System.out.println(i + "\t" + point[i].X + "\t" + point[i].Y + "\t" + positionX + "\t" + positionY + "\t" + differenceX + "\t" + differenceY);
    }
```

and this is the class function move.

```
public void move(int velocity, char direction, char direction2) {
    switch(direction) {
        case 'R':
            X += velocity;
        break;
        case 'L':
            X -= velocity;
        break;
        case 'U':
            Y -= velocity;
        break;
        case 'B':
            Y += velocity;
        break;
    }

    switch(direction2) {
        case 'R':
            X += velocity;
        break;
        case 'L':
            X -= velocity;
        break;
        case 'U':
            Y -= velocity;
        break;
        case 'B':
            Y += velocity;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: "here's some of my code"   please post a [mcve]

Comment: Could you share your input and control flow statement(s)? These snippets are not enough to reproduce the problem you're having.

Comment: @OldProgrammer done

Comment: Between the moment that you calculate `differenceX = positionX - point[i].X;` and the moment that you print out `point[i].X`, `positionX` and `differenceX` you already call `point[i].move()`. Therefore the `point[i].X` is no longer the value that you used to calculate the `differenceX`

Comment: @ThomasKläger u are right, thanks :)